# oracle case statement that returns group(min/max) results

Tags: oracle11g, group-by, case

I am tyring to create a case statement that will return a min or max a date field depending on the case.

Since there are group functions within the case, I think I need to put part or all of the statement in the group by section, but I get an error "ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here" when I try to put it in the group by section.

I am also trying to join to another table based on the same case statement and that does not seem to work either.

Here is the "offending"case statement:

> case 
>           when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then max(cn.CN_DATE)
>           else min(cn.CN_DATE) end as  Open_dt,

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        id.CUST_ID,  
        case
          when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then 'Flex Bundle'
            when id.UDAC_CODE = 'ELB1' then 'ELB1'
            when id.UDAC_CODE = 'ELB2' then 'ELB2'
            when id.UDAC_CODE in ('GAT2', 'GAT1W','START', 'STARTW') then 'Smart Start Bundle'
                  else 'Unknown'
            end as ProgramName,         
        case
             when CN.SIGN_TYPE = 'U' then ' 920'
            else id.DIV_NUM end as Div,
        case
            when CN.SIGN_TYPE = 'U' then '0920'
            else id.UNIT_NUM end as Unit,        
        case 
            when CN.SIGN_TYPE = 'U' then 9200
            else id.SALES_REP_ID end as Rep_ID,
        case 
            when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then max(cn.CN_DATE)
            else min(cn.CN_DATE) end as  Open_dt,            
         extract(year from case 
            when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then max(cn.CN_DATE)
            else min(cn.CN_DATE) end) as Yr,      
        To_Number(to_char(case 
            when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then max(cn.CN_DATE)
            else min(cn.CN_DATE) end,'IW'), '99') as  Wk, 
        sum(id.ITEM_NISD_AMT) as BundleNI   

    from 
        ICV.VZ_ITEM_DETAIL                            id
        join ICV.VZ_CUSTOMER                   vc  on (vc.CUSTOMER_ID = id.CUST_ID)
        left outer join (
            select  CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_ISSUE_NUM, min(CONTRACT_DATE) as CN_date, SIGN_TYPE
            from    VAST.CONTRACT                      
            where 
            SIGN_TYPE not in ( 'U', 'M', '-', 'C', 'L')
            group by   CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_ISSUE_NUM,  sign_type) cn
        on (ID.CUST_ID = CN.CUSTOMER_ID and ID.DIR_NUM = CN.PRODUCT_CODE 
                                                                        and id.DIR_ISSUE_NUM = cn.PRODUCT_ISSUE_NUM)
           where 
        (id.UDAC_CODE in ('ELB1', 'ELB2', 'GAT2', 'GAT1W','START', 'STARTW')
        or id.DISC_PGM_NUM in ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B'))
        and id.DIV_NUM in ('  C2', '  C3', '  C4', '  C6', '  N1', '  N2', ' 371', '  K3', '  K1', '  K2' , ' 275', ' 253', ' 368', ' 296')
        and id.ITEM_ACTION_CODE in ('A', 'I')
           and id.PAY_PERIOD_YR= '2015'
        and vc.SOURCE_SYSTEM_CDE= 'V'
        and id.HANDLED_PAY_PERIOD_YR is not null
        and HANDLED_PAY_PERIOD_NUM >=6

    group by
        id.CUST_ID,   
        case
            when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then 'Flex Bundle'
            when id.UDAC_CODE = 'ELB1' then 'ELB1'
            when id.UDAC_CODE = 'ELB2' then 'ELB2'
            when id.UDAC_CODE in ('GAT2', 'GAT1W','START', 'STARTW') then 'Smart Start Bundle'
            else 'Unknown'
            end,         
        case
             when CN.SIGN_TYPE = 'U' then ' 920'
            else id.DIV_NUM end,
        case
            when CN.SIGN_TYPE = 'U' then '0920'
            else id.UNIT_NUM end,        
        case 
            when CN.SIGN_TYPE = 'U' then 9200
            else id.SALES_REP_ID end,    
            case 
            when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then max(cn.CN_DATE)
            else min(cn.CN_DATE) end,            
         extract(year from case 
            when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then max(cn.CN_DATE)
            else min(cn.CN_DATE) end),      
        To_Number(to_char(case 
            when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then max(cn.CN_DATE)
            else min(cn.CN_DATE) end,'IW'), '99')
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You're allowed to have them in your CASE statement and they don't go in your GROUP BY. Show your full SQL and table structure if you're expecting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using single-row subquery in the THEN part of the CASE.
For eg.

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN  id.DISC_PGM_NUM IN ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B')
THEN 
(
SELECT MAX(cn.CN_DATE) FROM <table_name> cn
)
ELSE
(
SELECT MAX(cn.CN_DATE) FROM <table_name> cn
)
END AS Open_dt
FROM ....
```

Hope you get the solution to it.

Comment: Thanks Manish - What will I put in the "group by" section?

Comment: @MarkJustice - Where do you want to put the GROUP BY section? You can't put in the subquery part in the THEN section, because I already mentioned that it should be a single-row subquery.

Comment: I may need to enclose the entire query, so I  understand.  The table alias was "CN" that i put in the where clause with the following **left outer join (
        select  CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_ISSUE_NUM, min(CONTRACT_DATE) as CN_date, SIGN_TYPE
        from    VAST.CONTRACT                      
        where 
        SIGN_TYPE not in ( 'U', 'M', '-', 'C', 'L')
        group by   CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_ISSUE_NUM,  sign_type) cn
    on (ID.CUST_ID = CN.CUSTOMER_ID and ID.DIR_NUM = CN.PRODUCT_CODE and id.DIR_ISSUE_NUM = cn.PRODUCT_ISSUE_NUM)**

Comment: so would the case statement look like this? **case 
        when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then (select(max(CN_DATE) from cn)
        else (select min(CN_DATE) from cn) end as  Open_dt,**

Comment: @MarkJustice - Is it possible to show your full sql here? I probably need to see the whole of it to understand it...

Comment: Hi @MarkJustice, The code above won't work because of the MAX(cn.CN_DATE) written in the THEN part. You probably have to do it in the way I mentioned above. In the answer where I mentioned **<table_name> cn**, you probably have to write the whole cn subquery there, and then continue the same into the GROUP BY. You can try this and see how the query goes on(if it is error free or not). Or we can wait for someone else to intervene and say the correct way to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

Without having your schema to test with it's difficult to fully write out your large query.  But something like this will not work:

```
when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then max(cn.CN_DATE)
```

It doesn't work because DISC_PGM_NUM is not being grouped.

Now, if you aggregate DISC_PGM_NUM it can work.  Like this:

```
when max(id.DISC_PGM_NUM) in  ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then max(cn.CN_DATE)
```

The problem with that is that max(id.DISC_PGM_NUM) won't give you the value you're looking for.  If the record has values '15B' and '40B', '40B' will be your max and so it won't fit into the IN clause.  One way around this is to use a DECODE or another CASE statement.

For example:

```
when max(case when id.DISC_PGM_NUM in ('15B','20B','25B','24B','28B','33B') then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then max(cn.CN_DATE)
```

That will consider all the values you want as 1 and the others as 0 so that your max evaluates properly.

Check out this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a330e/10